# Escape out of 2 Javascript loops (or stop script)

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a quiz on my site that will submit if the time is up.  After the form submits (via jquery), I would like the timer to stop working.  I tried putting `return: false` after the test submits, but that didn't work.

html:

```
 <span id="time">30:00</span>
```

javascript:

```
var thirtyMinutes = 60 * 30,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
startTimer(thirtyMinutes, display);

function startTimer(duration, display) {
var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if ($('#time').html() == '00:00'){
            alert("There is no time left remaining.  The test will now submit.");
            $('#submitTest').trigger( "click" ); //submit the test

            //this is where I would like to exit the script and stop the timer from working
        }

    if (--timer < 0) {
        timer = duration;
    }

}, 1000);

}
```

Comment: `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop setInterval you have to use this

```
clearInterval(n);
```

And put

```
var n = setInterval(function () {....
```